# TikZ export from Geogebra

Tags: tikz-pgf, export, geogebra

I have one problem when I am exporting from GeoGebra a TikZ figure. Here is my GeoGebra graphic.

[image]

When I export it to TikZ I get this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-1.2,-1.06) rectangle (7.24,6.1);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (2.,5.)-- (1.,1.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (1.,1.)-- (4.,1.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (4.,1.)-- (2.,5.);
\draw [->,line width=2.pt] (-1.,0.) -- (7.,0.);
\draw [->,line width=2.pt] (0.,-1.) -- (0.,6.);
\draw (-0.48,6.04) node[anchor=north west] {$y$};
\draw (6.52,0.82) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.62,1.15) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (4.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.28,1.11) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.,5.) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.68,5.27) node {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code gives this figure:
[image]

The problem is that all the captions are moved and if you compare the two figures the only difference is in caption positions. Now I have to change the coordinates of the captions in the LaTeX code. Is there a faster way? I have figures with 20–25 captions and I would like to avoid doing this manual adjustment.

Comment: Unless you can instruct GeoGebra to export text/nodes differently, I don't see a way. (Or maybe you need to construct you GeoGebra diagram differently?) You could globally set some options that try to correct this but I don't see a common factor. The export is also a bit weird. I don't see a good reason for the axis labels to have `anchor=north west` while the vertex labels don't use an anchor. Does it actually “exports” `\usepackage{pgfplots}`? That's not good. You'd be better off writing your own TikZ pictures. With proper TikZ and named coordinates, you don't have to do anything manual.